# Force Angular to clean $cacheFactory after some action

Tags: angularjs, cachefactory

So we cache values from drop down in dropdown resourse module in this way

```
var cache = new CacheFactory('DropDownResource', {
      maxAge: 3600000,
      deleteOnExpire: 'aggressive',
      capacity: 5,
      storageMode: 'sessionStorage'
    });
```

And then in $http callback we save data for dropdown in this way

```
cache.put('dataForDropDown', data);
```

In other module we have posibility to change user setting especially to change language. After this action i need to clean cache. Because when user change language and goes to the page with dropdown he wants to see dropdown with needed language.

So at the page with dropdown we need to send call to server one more time. To do it we need to clean cache after language is change.

How can we do it?

I tries this code in drop down module.

> var cache = $cacheFactory('dataForDropDown');
>   cache.remove('dataForDropDown');

But it doesn't work. It says that cache with name dataForDropDown have been already created. I can't understand what i am doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to documentation, `$cacheFactory('name')` returns a new cache object. If you want to get the cache object to call its `removeAll` method write something like this:

```
angular.module('superCache')
  .factory('superCache', ['$cacheFactory', function($cacheFactory) {
    return $cacheFactory('super-cache');
  }]);
```

This registers a factory to your module. the factory `superCache` contains cache object. You can clear it by calling `removeAll` method. Or you can remove a specific item from your cache using `remove(key)` method and it is injectable (like other angular factories) in controllers and services.

Comment: I see this example. But the problem is how to get data from session storage via cacheFactory?

Comment: You can retrieve data from cache by calling cache objects `get` method.